# pytube json.decoder.JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, pytube

I am using the latest version of pytube3

Sometimes I get "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: ..."
when i use the code which is below.

```
import pytube
yt = pytube.YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q0oIoR9mLwc')
```

does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Isn’t that a [known](https://www.google.com/search?q=JSONDecodeError+pytube) bug? See [this GitHub Issue](https://github.com/nficano/pytube/issues/393).

Comment: I'm facing same problem.

Answer (score -1):

It turns out if you keep trying it will eventually download.
just make a try except block until the video gets downloaded.